# How to have an image be the size of a screen, yet have content below it?

Tags: html, css, responsive

When you load the page, I want an my image to be the size of the screen. I've obtained this, however any other text is now underneath the image as opposed to below the image (hopefully that makes sense).

```css
.main {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/616542814319415296/McCTpH_E.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

</div>

<h1>Hello World</h1>

<p>wtfffsk;dflaskjf;laksdjf;laskjf asdfals;kjfal as;flkajs f</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what browser support you need. If you're ok with the browser support [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units), you can use `100vw` and `100vh` to set the div to the viewport height/width, instead of using `100%`, and then simply remove the `position: absolute;`, as seen here:

```css
.main {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/616542814319415296/McCTpH_E.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

</div>

<h1>Hello World</h1>

<p>wtfffsk;dflaskjf;laksdjf;laskjf asdfals;kjfal as;flkajs f</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following CSS on the `main` element:

```
.main {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/616542814319415296/McCTpH_E.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

note: no `position: absolute`!

```css
.main {
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 background-image: url(https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/616542814319415296/McCTpH_E.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

</div>

<h1>Hello World</h1>

<p>wtfffsk;dflaskjf;laksdjf;laskjf asdfals;kjfal as;flkajs f</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the html and body have 100% height, you get the same effect without using vh/vw.

```css
html,body{height: 100%;}
.main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/616542814319415296/McCTpH_E.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main"></div>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<p>wtfffsk;dflaskjf;laksdjf;laskjf asdfals;kjfal as;flkajs f</p>
```